Why am I getting duplicate entries on table search results v-table vue js3/vuetify?
I'm trying to implement search functionality over the v-table data entries.
While I search, I'm getting the right data, But I can see duplicate rows.
I'm using pinia store to store data.
Here's the code:
LogDataTable.vue:
<template>
  <v-table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="log in logs" :key="log.logType">
        <!-- <td>{{  log.sn }}</td> -->
        <td>{{ log.timestamp }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.logType }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.logMessage }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </v-table>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
 defineProps({
  logs: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  }
})
</script>

Search.vue:
<template>
  <v-text-field variant="outlined" density="compact" @keyup="search">
    <img :src="searchIcon" width="20" class="mr-3" />
  </v-text-field>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const emit = defineEmits(['search'])
const search = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
  emit('search', e.target.value)
}
</script>

LogsPage.vue:
<template>
  <div>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="3">
        <Search @search="searchLogs" />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
  <LogDataTable v-bind:logs="logs" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import LogDataTable from '../components/LogDataTable.vue'
import Search from '../components/Search.vue'
import { useLogsStore } from '../stores/logsStore'

const { eventLogData } = storeToRefs(useLogsStore())
const { getEventLogData } = useLogsStore()

const searchText = ref('Search')
const eventlogJson = ref([])
const eventlogJsonTmp = ref([])
const logs = ref()

const filteredData = () => {

  console.log(searchText.value)
  if (searchText.value !== '') {
    console.log('Search text is not empty>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>')
    eventlogJson.value = eventlogJsonTmp.value
    logs.value = eventlogJson.value.filter(
      (eventLog) =>
        eventLog.timestamp.includes(searchText.value) ||
        eventLog.logType.includes(searchText.value) ||
        eventLog.logMessage.includes(searchText.value)
    )
    console.log('filtered log value inside if>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', logs.value)
  } else {
    logs.value = eventlogJsonTmp.value
    console.log('log value inside else>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', logs.value)
  }
}

const getJson = () => {
 /******  Some manipulations on the api data to create json ******?
        eventlogJson.value.push({
          timestamp: timestamp,
          logType: logType,
          logMessage: logMessage
        })
        console.log('logJson', eventlogJson.value)
        eventlogJsonTmp.value = eventlogJson.value
      }
    }
  }

  logs.value = eventlogJson.value
  console.log('logssssssssssss>>>>>>>>>>>', logs.value)
 
}

const searchLogs = (search) => {
  searchText.value = search
  filteredData()
}

const displayData = async () => {
  await getEventLogData()
  getJson()
}

onMounted(() => {
  displayData()
})
</script>


The data initially gets displayed correctly
When I search for some data, I can see duplicate entries getting displayed. Whats wrong here?

my best guess is logType has duplicate values, therefore v-for renders it again. can you sample something similar with the actual data?

Can you confirm with your Vue devtools that there is indeed duplication?

@Sombriks It works now.  And yes logType has duplicate values. That's why it wasn't working. The key in the v-for is actually not needed here. Thanks for pointing out

You should mark Sombriks comment as the answer, fyi.  The documentation states that the key must be unique: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list
